# Cant's code against Yun Wireless Section

Tags: arduino-yun, sketch

Just got my Yun today.  Successfully connected to my home wireless, installed YunSysUpgrade_v1.5.1, 
and divied up my Micro SD card for Linino and Windows file system with YunDiskSpaceExpander, 
and got files serving on the native file server from the SD card.

But I can't seem to touch the wireless section from a sketch.

I'm running a mod of the example ScanNetworks sketch - here's the relevant part:

```
void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  Serial.println("Version: ");
  Serial.println( fv );
  Serial.println("Status: ");
  Serial.println( WiFi.status() );
  // scan for existing networks:
  Serial.println("Scanning available networks...");
  listNetworks();
}
```

Here is the ouptut: no version and a status of 255 (which I cannot find documentation on....)

> Version:
>
> Status:
>   255 
>   Scanning available networks...
>   ** Scan Networks ** 
>   number of available networks:0

I looked at installing wifi_dnld.elf, but could not find jumper 3 on my Yun, so assumed it was for the 'true shield'.

What am I doing wrong, or do I need to return this to amazon?

Answer (score 1):

`WiFi` library won't work with the Yun: it's meant to work only with the WiFi shield.

On the Yun, everything but the pins is connected to the linux cpu. For the microcontroller to use all the devices available to linux, including wifi, you need to use the `Bridge` library. Try running example `WifiStatus` (Examples -> Bridge -> WifiStatus)

A drop in replacement (almost) of both Ethernet and WiFi libraries is the `YunClient`/`YunServer` pair, part of the `Bridge` library. Check out the docs at http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunBridgeLibrary.